# JQuery in JSF get element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I created a web page that print some text using JSF

I've added spaces using tag

```
<tr:spacer width="24px" />
```

between each word

I want to decrease the width value to 12 when browser window size getting smaller

I know it's possible to do this using Jquery.

Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
<tr:spacer class="spacer" width="24px" />
```

and use jquery to change the width using

```
$('.spacer').attr('width','12px');
```

To detect the browser resize you can use

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   // put here a check if window is smaller than what you want
   // and set your spacer size accordingly
});
```

But wondering, why don't you just use a percentage for the width? then it will scale automatically